# Console application running without program.cs file

Tags: c#

I have created a simple console application in c#. Is there any option to run the application without the default `program.cs` file?

Comment: whats the problem having program.cs?

Comment: I think it doesn't have your class name should `Program.cs` but you should have `Main` method which is entry point to your program..

Comment: The `.cs` file contains your source code, the `.exe` file contains the compiled program. After compiling, you don't need the `.cs` file to run the `.exe`

Comment: As @SonerGönül said we only need an entry point. Ive been in the same shoes today and argued with my colleague and he defended his idea -> this is the way aspnet and microsoft guided :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Program.cs` is not mandatory. Visual Studio creates a default `Program.cs` with a `Main` method for you to be able to run the application just after creating it.You only need an entry point. And for console application it is the `Main` method.

Comment: It has to start with uppercase M: `Main`.

Answer (score 9):

You need to have a `Main()` method in your console application. It doesn't have to be in `program.cs` though.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228506%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> Every C# application must contain a single Main method specifying where program execution is to begin.

Answer (score 2):

you can rename program.cs to any filename.cs of your choice, IDE will ask you to rename all its refrences , just click OK and it will work fine.

Name does not matter, you just need to have Main() method inside any cs file and it will be detected automatically.